# What's the length of a extended key?

Tags: bip32-hd-wallets

I'm reading [Mastring Bitcoin/ch05](https://github.com/bitcoinbook/bitcoinbook/blob/develop/ch05.asciidoc#extended-keys). In this chapter, it says "Because the extended key is 512 or 513 bits, it is also much longer than other Base58Check-encoded strings we have seen previously."

Why can an extended key be 513 bits long? I think it should be: pub/private-key(256bits) + chain-code(256bits) = 512bits.

Comment: Does this answers your question? https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/114314/how-the-extended-key-in-wallet-is-512-bits